# LSI MegaRaid SAS 9271-4i - "Upgrade Key Missing" after 2012R2 update

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, sas, megaraid, raid-controller

We have a ZealBox server 2012R2 with Supermicro mainboard and an attached LSI MegaRaid SAS 9271-4i controller running a RAID 1.

After a normal Windows Update and a following attempt to reboot, the computer doesn't boot any more and shows the following error message:

[image: Upgrade Key Missing]

This is from the bare controller, no extensions installed, and it doesn't matter if the drives are connected.

We have absolutely no idea what this could be or how the "key" was present before. "Connected" sounds like a physical key, there never was such a thing in the machine. What happened here and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know on your server but on Dell PERCs (which are rebranded LSI MegaRaid cards) they look a little something like [this](http://3.imimg.com/data3/PH/IH/MY-4538454646/-kgrhqj-h-e2ek3wbkhbnuqwy2f-q-_35-500x500.jpg) from [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/619903/upgrade-key-not-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know on Dell servers, there is a little daughter board with something like a 10 pin header connector. Sometimes that daughter board needs to be removed and re-seated.

Otherwise, you probably have a hardware failure.